# Select all rows that have at least a list of features

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I have EXPERIMENTAL_RUNS (runId), each of which have any number of SENSORS (sensorId) associated with them. With that in mind, I have an RS table to join the two:

```
==========
RS
==========
runId, sensorId
```

Thus if the run with runId=1 had sensors with sensorId=1, sensorId=6, sensorId=8 in it, there would be 3 entries in the RS table:
(runId=1, sensorId=1)
(runId=1, sensorId=6)
(runId=1, sensorId=8)

Is this really how I would return all EXPERIMENTAL_RUNS that have sensors {11,13,15}? From what I've read, what I seem to want is a nested hash join... Is this what's going to happen?

```
SELECT a.runId
FROM rs a, rs b, rs c
WHERE
a.runId=b.runId AND
b.runId=c.runId AND
a.sensorId=11 AND
a.sensorId=13 AND
b.sensorId=15
```

To clarify, I want to return only the EXPERIMENTAL_RUNS that have sensors 11 AND 13 AND 15.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have hash joins. But the query you posted should give you the results you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `runId, sensorId` are unique in the `rs` table, this will find the `runId`s that have all 3 `sensorId`s:

```
SELECT runId, COUNT(c) ct
FROM rs
WHERE sensorId IN (11, 13, 15)
GROUP BY runId
HAVING ct = 3
```